# put only certain instances of VPC behind NAT Gateway & leave the rest out

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, routing, nat, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC with several ec2 instances. Each one has a public ip + is able to communicate with each other over local 10.0.0.0 network + have internet access over internet gateway.

I need to put only several of those instances behind NAT Gateway with Elastic IP assigned to it, so when they connect to a certain outside service, they have the same public ip.

The problem is that I can't find a way to put only certain members of VPC behind this NAT Gateway. I can edit routing table for the VPC in general & that's it.

I couldn't find a way to create another VPC & include only certain members of the first VPC into it.

So what is the best way to do that?

P.S. it is a NAT Gateway, not a NAT instance.

So i have created a new subnet for the VPC, created a new network interface & attached it to one of the instances:
The instance got the new ip from this subnet & the new route was created automatically:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-10-0-1-1.ec2 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         ip-10-0-200-1.e 0.0.0.0         UG    10001  0        0 eth1
10.0.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.200.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
instance-data.e *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](https://serverfault.com/q/859140/153161) more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will needs to create a 2nd Subnet in your VPC. You would then deploy the EC2 instances that need NAT to that subnet. They will pick up private IPs from that subnet. Next create a new Route table and associate it with the new subnet. finally adjust the new route table and add a default route of 0.0.0.0/0 that uses your NAT Gateway.

The NAT Gateway should be deployed to your existing public subnet so that it can take advantage of the Internet gateway.

Hope this helps.

Mike.

Comment: when I create a NAT Gateway I must select the subnet it is attached to. So I choose the new subnet 10.0.200.0/24, right? The Internet Gateway is "attached" to VPC, not the subnet.

Comment: Hi there, no choose the public subnet to deploy your NAT Gateway to(the original subnet). NAT Gatways need to be deployed to public subnets so they can use the Internet Gateway to get to the internet. the EC2 instances that you deploy to the new subnet, with the new route table will be able to use the NAT Gateway

Comment: OK, so the original subnet with access to internet gateway is 10.0.1.0/24.
I have created a new NAT Gateway & attached it to this subnet & it received an 10.0.1.104 address. 
I'm confused about the purpose of creation of the second 10.0.200.0/24 subnet, but if it's supposed to work like that - ok.
Now if I go to the "VPC Dashboard->Route tables" I can see only 1 route table for the VPC & if I edit it, then every instance in the VPC will be affected. If I edit it & replace "igw-fd92" for 0.0.0.0/0 with "nat-01ed" then I'll lose connection to all instances in it,right? How do I avoid it?

Comment: OK, you've got the second subnet, now you need to create a new Route table, associate the new route table with the new subnet and add the default route 0.0.0.0/0 with nat-01ed to that. then deploy EC2 instance to the new subnet and they will be able to use the NAT Gateway

Comment: Here is a link to details on AWS NAT Gateways: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Comment: If you create a new routing table in "VPC Dashboard->Route tables" then you must associate it with the vpc, not the subnet http://www.screencast.com/t/vNOfoCsTPBs7

Comment: Anyway, I have created the new routing table & added 0.0.0.0/0 + "nat-01ed" to it.
The only instance,which has a network interface attached to the new 10.0.200.0/24 subnet has the following routing table now:
# ip route show
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
default via 10.0.200.1 dev eth1  metric 10001
10.0.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.69
10.0.200.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.200.234
169.254.169.254 dev eth0

Comment: Now how do I make this instance use the NAT Gateway for internet connectivity & f.e. return the new elastic ip if I do "curl ifconfig.co"?

At the same time I need to be able to connect to the instance's public ip via ssh, serve some web content on the http port & etc?

Comment: Its true about the route table, you associate it with the VPC but then you must go into the route table and add the default route (I see you have done that). Next go to your new route table and on the route association tab make sure it is associated with the newly created subnet. at the end of this process the Public subnet should be associated with the original route table and the new subnet with the new route table.

Comment: The SSH stuff is now a different question, if your EC2 instances can now use the NAT server then this question is answered. if it is can you mark my answer as correct please. then you can post another questions explaining you HTTP and SSH needs.

Comment: I can see that the newly created routing table is automatically associated with all the subnets I have. Is it ok like that or do I have to remove the new 10.0.200.0/24 subnet from the original (prod) routing table & remove the original 10.0.1.0/24 subnet from the new (prod-nat) routing table? The #route still returns the same as in my original post & curl returns the same  original public ip, so the NAT Gateway is not used I guess. Also, how do I test it's usage if I lose connection to the instance? Thanks for you explanations, I think we're almost there :)

Comment: HI. now you are on the new route table, on the subnet association tab click edit, tick the box next to your new subnet (the private subnet you want t use NAT) and then click Save. this subnet is now associated with your new route table. the original subnet needs to left Delete repeated word and keeps it association with the original subnet.

Comment: The new subnet association->edit looks like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/2IbcFqAIndp0 + https://www.screencast.com/t/ytqGuK3Dw . But the original routing table looks like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/9nebQnQ9y + https://www.screencast.com/t/utesrvnfbD . Now do I have to explicitly associate the original routing table with the 3 subnets in there or I just leave it as it is as they're all on "main route table" & the new one is on "rtb-b12374c9 | prod-nat"? When I associated the new routing table with new subnet & old with old+saved, nothing changed if I do #route or #ip route show :(

Comment: Hi leave the old route table as it is. like you said because it is the main route table it will be associated with all subnets that haven't been explicitly associated with another route table. all should now work. to summarise. 1 VPC at least 2 Subnets, the first subnet is a public subnet using a route table with a default route of 0.0.0.0/0 using the internet Gateway. the second subnet is a private subnet using a route table that has a default route using the NAT Gateway.

Comment: other than that if it still not working you can link screen shots of your config and I can take a look

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated!! It doesn't work, so here's the ifconfig + ip route show from the instance with the network interface with new subnet attached: https://www.screencast.com/t/kZ9grEQhmCA . The route table configs from the amazon web interface you saw in my message above. What else do you need? Again, my main goal is to make the instances return the same ip with curl ifconfig.co , but not to lose connectivity over ssh & http over their public ips.

Comment: This is an attempt to do something here that falls into the category of "it simply doesn't work that way."  You're trying to NAT the outbound traffic from instances that are on a *public* subnet.  These instances already have public IPs.  Naturally, once you apply the NAT, the instances' public IPs aren't going to work, because of the inevitable route asymmetry through the NAT gateway.

Comment: I agree with you. once you have enabled the EC2 instance to communicate through the NAT gateway then that is what they will do. the original question didn't mention anything other than getting EC2 instances to work with a NAT Gateway. if they are connecting to the internet through the NAT gateway then the questions is answered. anything else need to be put into a different question.

Comment: As you can see from my screenshots the routing through NAT Gateway isn't working, right, so I can't mark the question answered? Now ok, forget about the instance being accessible from the internet, let's put it behind NAT Gateway first :) Is it because the metric for the route is 10001? And is it a problem that #ip route show gives "default via 10.0.200.1 dev eth1  metric 10001" rather than 10.0.1.104, which is the ip of the NAT Gateway? Any suggestion about how to connect to the instance after we put it behind nat & test the "curl ifconfig.co" will be additionally appreciated :)

Comment: The instance itself looks like this if it helps: https://www.screencast.com/t/TJSr2F5Ze

Comment: I think it could be that. Can you connect to an instance in the Public subnet and jump over to an instance in the Private subnet? I have a college that is a Linux dude. ill send him an email and ask him if he has any ideas.

Comment: I think it is an Linux configuration now and not an AWS configuration issue. it looks like you have all of those pieces in place

Comment: Yes I can. I have attached a second network interface to another instance (with the same config). It received the new subnet ip=10.0.200.90. Then I ssh'ed to it's public ip & from there ssh'ed to the ip of the first instance in the same subnet ip=10.0.200.234.

Comment: OK, looks like I made a progress myself & as you've said it's a Linux configuration now: "#ping ifconfig.co" returned "188.113.88.193", so I did: "#ip route add 188.113.88.193 via 10.0.1.104 dev eth0" & voala "#curl ifconfig.co" returned the external Elastic IP of the NAT Gateway :) 10.0.1.104 is it's internal IP. Is it possible to do smth like that through the Amazon web interface? We're preparing for the auto-scaling & changing routing rules inside each instance will be not a very good thing :(

Comment: Hi Valeri, can we take a recap. is the Linux box on the private subnet now routing through the NAT Gateway? as regards auto scaling you can create your own Launch configuration already configured as needed. i'm offline for a few hours now but will pick things up tomorrow.

Comment: The Linux box on the private subnet 10.0.200.0/24 is working as before, but when I add a custom route to it with "route add -host ifconfig.co gw 10.0.1.104" then the traffic to ifconfig.co is going through the 10.0.1.104 which is an internal ip of the NAT Gateway & curl returns the correct external ip of the NAT Gateway with "#curl ifconfig.co" after that.